# What kind of features are extracted with the AlexNet layers?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Question is regarding [this method](https://se.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/alexnet.html), which extracts features from the FC7 layer of AlexNet.

What kind of features is it actually extracting?

I used this method on images of paintings done by two artists.  The training set is about 150 training images from each artist (so that the features are stored in a 300x4096 matrix); the validation set is 40 images. This works really well, 85-90% correct classification.  I would like to know why it works so well.

Comment: First of all this does not seem correct. This is a feed forward layer with 4096 neurons, so Kx4096 suggests that you passed K input images. Yet neither training (150) nor testing (40) does not match K=300, so something is wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, 150 per artist so 300 in total.

Answer (score 1):

**WHAT FEATURES ?**

FC8 is the classification layer; FC7 is the one before it, where all of the prior kernel pixels are linearised and concatenated.  These represent the abstract, top-level features that the model training has "discovered".  To examine these features, try one of the many layer visualization tools available on line (don't ask for references here; SO bans requests for resources).

The features vary from one training to another, depending on the kernel initialization (usually random) and very dependent on the training set.  However, the features tend to be simple in the early layers, with greater variety and detail in the later ones.  For instance, on the original AlexNet target (ILSVRC 2012, a.k.a. ImageNet data set), the FC7 features often include vehicle tires, animal faces, various types of flower petals, green leaves and stems, two-legged animal torsos, airplane sections, car/truck/bus grill work, etc.

Does that help?

**WHY DOES IT WORK SO WELL ?**

That depends on the data set and training parameters.  How different are the images from the artists?  There are plenty of features to extract: choice of subject, palette, compositional complexity, hard/soft edges, even direction of brush strokes.  For instance, differentiating any two early cubists could be a little tricky; telling Rembrandt from Jackson Pollack should hit 100%.